# VHDL FSM not working as expected

Tags: vhdl, state-machines

I am not that experienced in VHDL. I am trying to implement a simple state machine that goes through 3 states - from idle, to DUT_run for 10 clock cycles, then remains at the done state. However the screenshot below shows the unexpected behaviour of oscillating between DUT_run and done states. And sometimes it jumps straight from idle to done. Can anyone figure out my mistakes?

ILA screenshot of behaviour:

[image: ILA screenshot]

Code:

```
    
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;

entity top_level is
Port (clk_i         : in std_logic;  --100MHz
      sw15_reset_i  : in std_logic;  --active high
      start_button  : in std_logic;
      sw0_i : in std_logic;         --for testing fsm
      led0_o        : out std_logic  --fsm 1 done led 
     );
end top_level;

architecture Behavioral of top_level is

signal clk_100MHz    : std_logic;
signal rst           : std_logic;
signal rst_n         : std_logic;

signal DUT_count            : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal fsm1_count           : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal fsm1_done            : std_logic;

signal fifo_wr_en        : std_logic;
signal fifo_rd_en        : std_logic;
signal fifo_full         : std_logic;
signal fifo_empty        : std_logic;
signal fifo_data_out     : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal fifo_stored_words : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

signal DUT_reset_command : std_logic;

type State_type is (fsm1_S_idle , fsm1_S_DUT_run , fsm1_S_done);
signal fsm1_Current_State , fsm1_Next_State : State_type;

attribute keep : boolean;
attribute keep of rst_n                : signal is true;
attribute keep of rst                  : signal is true;
attribute keep of DUT_count            : signal is true;
attribute keep of fsm1_count           : signal is true;
attribute keep of fsm1_done            : signal is true;

attribute keep of fifo_wr_en        : signal is true;
attribute keep of fifo_rd_en        : signal is true;
attribute keep of fifo_full         : signal is true;
attribute keep of fifo_empty        : signal is true;
attribute keep of fifo_data_out     : signal is true;
attribute keep of fifo_stored_words : signal is true;
attribute keep of DUT_reset_command : signal is true;

attribute keep of FSM1_Current_State : signal is true;
attribute keep of FSM1_Next_State    : signal is true;

component clk_wiz_0 
Port (clk_in     : in std_ulogic; 
      clk_100MHz : out std_ulogic);
end component;

--component fifo_generator_0
--  PORT (
--    clk        : IN STD_LOGIC;
--    srst       : IN STD_LOGIC;
--    din        : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
--    wr_en      : IN STD_LOGIC;
--    rd_en      : IN STD_LOGIC;
--    dout       : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
--    full       : OUT STD_LOGIC;
--    empty      : OUT STD_LOGIC;
--    data_count : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0)
--  );
--END COMPONENT;
signal test_start_button           : std_logic;
signal test_state           : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);

attribute keep of test_start_button : signal is true;
attribute keep of test_state : signal is true;

begin

--- Synchronising reset button with clock and inverting ---
rst    <= sw15_reset_i when rising_edge(clk_100MHz);
rst_n  <= not rst;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
--- Clock wizard component instantiation ---

Clock_Wizard_inst : clk_wiz_0
    Port map(clk_in      => clk_i,                 
             clk_100MHz  => clk_100MHz);

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
--- FIFO generator wizard component instantiation ---
 
--FIFO_generator_0_inst : fifo_generator_0
--    PORT MAP (clk        => clk_100MHz,
--              srst       => rst,
--              din        => DUT_count(7 downto 0),
--              wr_en      => fifo_wr_en,
--              rd_en      => fifo_rd_en,
--              dout       => fifo_data_out,
--              full       => fifo_full,
--              empty      => fifo_empty,
--              data_count => fifo_stored_words
--  );
  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- Counter to emulate program counter data to test FIFO ---

DUT_counter : Process (clk_100MHz, DUT_reset_command)

begin

if (DUT_reset_command = '0') then
    DUT_count <= x"00000000";
    
elsif (rising_edge(clk_100MHz)) then        
    DUT_count <= DUT_count + 1;
    
end if;

end Process;

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- fsm 1 for controlling the reset signal of DUT and the write enable of FIFO ---

test_start_button <= sw0_i;

fsm_1 : Process (clk_100MHz, rst_n)

begin

if (rst_n = '0') then
    fsm1_Current_State <= fsm1_S_idle;
    fsm1_count         <= "00000000";
    
elsif (rising_edge(clk_100MHz)) then
    fsm1_Current_State <= fsm1_Next_State;

    case fsm1_Current_State is

    when fsm1_S_idle =>

        if (test_start_button = '0') then
            fsm1_Next_State <= fsm1_S_idle;
        
        else
            fsm1_Next_State <= fsm1_S_DUT_run;
    
        end if;

    when fsm1_S_DUT_run =>

        fsm1_count <= fsm1_count + 1;
   
        if (fsm1_count = 10-1) then
            fsm1_Next_State <= fsm1_S_done;
            fsm1_count <= "00000000";
        
        else
            fsm1_Next_State <= fsm1_S_DUT_run;

        end if;

    when fsm1_S_done =>
        
        fsm1_Next_State <= fsm1_S_done;
 
    end case;
    
    end if;
    
end Process;

fsm1_outputs : Process (fsm1_Current_State)

begin

case fsm1_Current_State is

when fsm1_S_idle =>
    test_state        <= "01";
    fifo_wr_en        <= '0';
    DUT_reset_command <= '0';
    fsm1_done    <= '0';

when fsm1_S_DUT_run =>
    test_state <= "10";
    fifo_wr_en     <= '1';
    DUT_reset_command <= '1';
    fsm1_done    <= '0';

when fsm1_S_done =>
    test_state <= "11";
    fifo_wr_en     <= '0';
    DUT_reset_command <= '0';
    fsm1_done    <= '1';
    
end case;

end Process;

--led0_o <= fsm_1_done;

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, you have "pipelined" your state machine by having registers for both `fsm1_Current_State` and `fsm1_Next_State`. This creates a one-clock delay before `fsm1_Next_State` can affect the current state.

Normally, if one is going to code a state machine in this style, only the current state is a register, and the next state is determined by a purely combinatorial process — just like how you're producing the FSM outputs.

Try adding `fsm1_Next_State` to your waveform display to see the delay that I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks Dave, this solved my issue. I now understand my mistake. Only the current_state reg should be updated synchronously and the next state should be combinatorial logic.